# What does it mean by "a cheery lot"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> Chuckling about Malfoy, they waited, Norbert thrashing about in his crate. About ten minutes later, four broomsticks came swooping down out of the darkness. **Charlie's friends were a cheery lot.** They showed Harry and Hermione the harness they'd rigged up, so they could suspend Norbert between them.
>
> -*Harry potter and the sorcerer's stone (J.K Rowling)*

'Cheery' means happy and cheerful, but what does it mean by 'they were a cheery lot'? Is it saying

(A) Charlie's friends were very (= a lot) cheery?

(B) Charlie's friends were a lot of people, and they were all cheery?

For me neither of these seems right because I think 'a' and 'lot' cannot be written separately since 'a lot' as a whole means 'very or very much'. And also it looks weird to put an adjective 'cheery' between 'a' and 'lot'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, yes, they can be written "separately". *A* is the usual indefinite article, whereas *lot* is a noun that is synonymous with *group* or *bunch*. Here's an entry I found from the Oxford Dictionaries Online:

> [lot](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lot)
>   1 informal treated as singular or plural A particular group or set of people or things.
>   *‘it's just one lot of rich people stealing from another’*
>   *‘he will need a second lot of tills to handle the second currency’*
>   1.1 British with adjective A group of a specified kind (used in a derogatory or dismissive way)
>   *‘an inefficient lot, our Council’*

I doubt it's being used in a "derogatory" way in the story, as the dictionary suggests. It simply means that Charlie's friends were a cheery ***group***. I don't think it suggests that there were many (= a lot) of friends, just enough to constitute a "group".

On a side note, I feel like you're more likely to see a different noun, like *bunch* (cheery bunch), in AmE. It's understandable in any case.

Comment: As a Brit I actually read "a cheery lot" to mean "a miserable bunch". We can be awfully sarcastic over here.

Comment: Also as a brit, I think any phrase "they are a ___ lot" is almost always meant sarcastically.

Comment: @AlanThird May I ask you what does it mean by "miserable" ? Doesn't cheery and miserable have the opposite meaning? Are you saying that's what the author intended to say? But why does she use sarcasm here?

Comment: @AlanThird In fairness it's not always sarcastic. Usually the phrase is "a right cheery lot" if it's intended to be sarcastic. Or at least, it's posed as a question "weren't they a cheery lot?" or stated in a more obviously-sarcastic way "well they were a right cheery lot!". (Also for some reason I imagine the phrase in either a Yorkshire or Scotch accent because it seems to be more fitting.)

Comment: @dbwlsld they are saying that she is not using sarcasm, but they would usually interpret that in everyday talk as sarcasm.

Comment: @Pharap funnily enough I am a Scot. I get the impression that the further north you travel, the more likely sarcasm will be used in every day conversation. I don't know if that's true, though.

Comment: @stephenS "a cheery lot" *can* mean they were cheerful, but unless the context shows otherwise, my assumption is that it means they weren't. I don't know that JKR would be thinking "I'll use sarcasm here", it's just how we speak. It's idiomatic. We can't be sure, though, without asking her, unless there's more context in the surrounding text.

Comment: @Alan Third it may be a personal thing, I would take the opposite view and presume that " a cheery lot" meant they were happy, unless the context suggested otherwise. If Tony Hancock said it well it certainly would be sarcastic, though.

Comment: @AlanThird I've never heard "cheery lot" to actually mean happy group, usually, as you say, it's used sarcastically. However it doesn't really make sense in this context, I think, why they would be miserable. Showing off their gear seems like a happy, fun thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

In the sentence you cited the word "lot" is a noun. A lot is a group of people (please see [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lot_4), meaning 2).

I'd say that Charlie and his friends were good company, it was very enjoyable for Harry and Hermione to be with them.

Answer (score 3):

"Lot" in this sentence has the meaning of "bunch", group", "collection of people". It doesn't have the meaning that they are all in one group in any formal manner (although here the people are all friends of Charlie).

It means they can be discussed as a group for the moment - I might see a lot of people waiting for a bus in the rain, who don't know each other, and say they look like a miserable lot, meaning, a miserable bunch of people. Or some dogs outside a butcher shop and comment that they look like a hungry or optimistic lot. It also carries a sense of "offhand" informality, there's no formal "group", it's not a usage you would use in formal writing.

The book is using it this way. The author (who is speaking and describing them) is saying that the bunch of people who are arriving are, overall, cheerful (or a set of cheerful looking individuals) in their appearance.

Answer (score 1):

This phrase is usually used ironically, i.e. to convey the opposite of what is said. In this case they were clearly not a cheery lot at all, they were a dubious bunch of pranksters.